# Slow search query with a one to many join

Tags: mysql, search, relationship

My problem is a slow search query with a one-to-many relationship between the tables. My tables look like this.

Table Assignment

```
CREATE TABLE `Assignment` (
`Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ProjectId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`AssignmentTypeId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`AssignmentNumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`AssignmentNumberExternal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`DateStart` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`DateEnd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`DateDeadline` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`DateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
`Lon` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `idx_assignment_assignment_type_id` (`AssignmentTypeId`),
KEY `idx_assignment_assignment_number` (`AssignmentNumber`),
KEY `idx_assignment_assignment_number_external` 
(`AssignmentNumberExternal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table ExtraFields

```
CREATE TABLE `ExtraFields` (
`assignment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`value` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`assignment_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My search query

```
SELECT 
`Assignment`.`Id`, COL_5_72, COL_5_73, COL_5_74, COL_5_75, COL_5_76, 
COL_5_77 FROM ( 
SELECT 
`Assignment`.`Id`, 
`Assignment`.`AssignmentNumber` AS COL_5_72,
`Assignment`.`AssignmentNumberExternal` AS COL_5_73 ,
`AssignmentType`.`Name` AS COL_5_74,
`Assignment`.`DateStart` AS COL_5_75,
`Assignment`.`DateEnd` AS COL_5_76,
`Assignment`.`DateDeadline` AS COL_5_77 FROM `Assignment`
CASE WHEN `ExtraField`.`Name` = "WorkDistrict" THEN 
`ExtraField`.`Value` end as COL_5_78 FROM `Assignment`
    LEFT JOIN `ExtraFields` as `ExtraField` on 
`ExtraField`.`assignment_id` = `Assignment`.`Id`            
WHERE `Assignment`.`Deleted` IS NULL -- Assignment should not be removed.
AND (1=1) -- Add assignment filters.
) AS q1 
GROUP BY `Assignment`.`Id` 
HAVING 1 = 1 
AND COL_5_78 LIKE '%Amsterdam East%'
ORDER BY COL_5_72 ASC, COL_5_73 ASC;
```

When the table is only around 3500 records my query takes a couple of seconds to execute and return the results.

What is a better way to search in the related data? Should I just add a JSON field to the Assignment table and use the MySQL 5.7 Json query features? Or did I made a mistake in designing my database?

Comment: SELECT 
    `Assignment`.`Id`, 
    `Assignment`.`AssignmentNumber` AS COL_5_72,
    `Assignment`.`AssignmentNumberExternal` AS COL_5_73 ,
    `AssignmentType`.`Name` AS COL_5_74,
    `Assignment`.`DateStart` AS COL_5_75,
    `Assignment`.`DateEnd` AS COL_5_76,
    `Assignment`.`DateDeadline` AS COL_5_77 FROM `Assignment`..... GROUP BY BY `Assignment`.`Id` is bad SQL and can result in wrong results read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: make the primary_key of the ExtraFields table only consist of assignment_id. Or make an extra index with only assigment_id, might speed up the query.

Comment: Also unsure what the nested select is for it seems as it only changes the names of the columns?

Comment: You're using the (horrible no good) nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` in a way that obscures your query's intention. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  You *may* be using a `HAVING` clause where you should be using a `WHERE` clause. That will hammer performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using  select from subquery that forces MySQL to create unindexed temp table for each execution. Remove subquery (you really don't need it here) and it will be much faster.